# Heroku CLI Login - Error Code: mfa_required

Tags: heroku, headless, heroku-cli

I’ve been trying to login to HEROKU CLI on a headless Ubuntu. So, I don’t have a chance to open a browser. That’s why, I need to login with credential or any other method but there are only two login options which are browser, credentials.

Is there anybody face with the same problem?

Command:

```
heroku login -i
```

Error Message:

```
›   Error: Your account has MFA enabled; API requests using basic authentication with email and password are not supported. Please generate an authorization token 

›   for API access.

›

›   Error ID: mfa_required
```

PS: The Heroku doesn’t allow me to disable MFA.

Answer (score 4):

[Shanshan Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7184078/shanshan-chen) is basically right, but given the specifics of your issue you're still going to need the `-i` flag. I have had the same issue and was able to log in successfully using these steps:

1. Run `heroku login -i`
2. Enter your email address as normally
3. For the password, use your Heroku account API Key (see below)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try `heroku login` and use API key as the password. Feel free to refer to
[Not able login to Heroku account from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105084/not-able-login-to-heroku-account-from-command-line)