# Not able to log in to Heroku account from command line

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, command-line, multi-factor-authentication, codio

I am using codio.com. From there I am using the Ubuntu terminal to log into Heroku but it's giving me the below error. I have read the help [page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multi-factor-authentication#enabling-mfa-and-registering-verification-methods) also. It says with MFA you have to use browser for login. But the issue is, browser is not opening from Codio platform. I am stuck at this point. Please help.

```
codio@actor-spoon:~/workspace/helloSaas$ heroku login -i                 
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: prashantexploring@gmail.com
Password: ********
 ›   Error: Your account has MFA enabled; API requests using basic 
 ›   authentication with email and password are not supported. Please 
 ›   generate an authorization token for API access. 
 ›
 ›   Error ID: vaas_enrolled
```

Working :) : Just paste API key in place of password.

```
codio@magic-savage:~/workspace/rottenpotatoes$ heroku login -i
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.45.0 to 7.59.2.
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: prashantexploring@gmail.com
Password: ************************************
Logged in as prashantexploring@gmail.com
codio@magic-savage:~/workspace/rottenpotatoes$
```

Comment: Does this help? - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multi-factor-authentication#enabling-mfa-and-registering-verification-methods

Comment: No . I already read that but got no solution .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can use the "API Key" as the password.
[image]

Comment: Instead of password , need to paste API key .
<code>
codio@magic-savage:~/workspace/rottenpotatoes$ heroku login -i
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.45.0 to 7.59.2.
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: prashantexploring@gmail.com
Password: ************************************
Logged in as prashantexploring@gmail.com
codio@magic-savage:~/workspace/rottenpotatoes$ 
</code>

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to disable MFA
[UI_PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEmNj.png)

Go here to browse account setting
Scroll down and reveal / re-generate the API-KEY
[API_KEY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C8B7.png)

Then login in cli by

```
heroku login -i
```

type your email and use API Key as password, you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

Enter "heroku login -i" in an active virtual terminal session then enter your email.

Use a browser to access https://dashboard.heroku.com/account, scroll down to API Key, click on Reveal, copy the key and paste as your password. Hit enter and you should be logged in.

Answer (score -3):

Disable two-factor authentication in your heroku account settings.

> You can disable two-factor authentication from the Dashboard account page. You will be asked to supply your password for added security. You can also disable it from the CLI with the following command:
>
> ```
> $ heroku 2fa:Disable
> ```
>
> This will also ask for your password.

(From [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/two-factor-authentication#disabling-two-factor-authentication).)